# most efficient way to check correct input and/or produce error and re-enter

Tags: c++, input

I have a piece of code that requires a lot of user inputs. I would like to ensure the correct input type has been entered by the user and if not, prompt them to enter something that is correct.

Now I could do this with a fair amount of `if` statements covering all possible inputs but I'm certain there must be a better, more efficient way. I've seen a few possible alternate solutions (e.g.`typeid`,`throw/catch`) around but they seem to divide people on whether it's good programming technique or not.

So what is the best way to get around this problem?

I've outlined what I know/need from the incoming inputs:

- I know what type the user should be inputting (they're either `ints`,`doubles` or `strings`).
- I need to check that they have entered the correct input, and if not prompt them to enter an input of type `X`.
- The code preferably needs to be stored in a function (or template etc...) and applicable to all 3 cases as there are many instances when this check/read needs to be performed.

I should also note I'm using `getline(cin,X)` as some of my inputs contain spaces. Here is the code I am referring to:

```
        while(again==1){
            cout<<"Please enter student name: "<<endl;
            sName=clear_and_read<string>();
            cout<<"Please enter student ID: "<<endl;
            sID=clear_and_read<int>();
            cout<<"What course does the student study? (1)Physics etc...."<<endl;
            sCourse=clear_and_read<int>();
            cout<<"How many results would you like to enter for this student?: "<<endl;
            d=clear_and_read<int>();
            student* S1= new physics(sName,sID);  //*********
            //physics S1(sName,sID);
            if(sCourse==1){
                for(int i(0);i<d;i++){
                    string cName("Nill"); double cResult(0);int cCode(0);
                    cout<<"Please enter course "<<i+1<<" code: "<<endl;
                    cCode=clear_and_read<int>();
                    cout<<"Please enter course "<<i+1<<" title: "<<endl;
                    cName=clear_and_read<string>();;
                    cout<<"Please enter result "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
                    cResult=clear_and_read<double>();;
                    (*S1).addresult(cName,cCode,cResult);
                }           
            }
            //allstudents.insert(pair<int,student*>(sID,S1)); //********* 
            allstudents[sID]=S1;    //THIS LINE
            cout<<"Would you like to enter another student manually? (1)Yes (2)No :"<<endl;
            again=clear_and_read<int>();;
        }
```

Where currently I have made the **unfinished** template function `clear_and_read` that was going to check that the incoming data was the same as typed into the template, but I was stuck on how to do this.

```
template <class T> T clear_and_read(){ //NOT CORRECT YET
    string name;
    cin.ignore();//skips "enter" still in cin stream
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin,name);
    T typeoutput;



    //needs to check for valid type
        //assign name to typeoutput
    return typeoutput;
}
```

Before inserting this template class, the code `sName=clear_and_read<string>();` would have just been `getline(cin,sName);` and etc..

As a side note, what I mean by "a fair amount of `if` statements" is that it would require a if-check/else statement after every required input.

Am I over-complicating things?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Show the code that you want to improve. It's difficult to say what the problem is. There's pretty much a single way to prompt the user until something acceptable is entered, and it typically doesn't involve a lot of `if`s.